# dealing with voice in java

Tags: java, voice

does any one know how to capture voice and send it through a network then play it on another computer in java

Answer (score 2):

I did some research on this about 10 years ago at a research lab so I might be a bit out of date! At the time there was no standard for the whole process. You have to use the [Java sound API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/) to record and playback, then any network protocol you want to send it.

If it is just for a person to listen to, then use something with good compression - something like the [media streaming in the Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/support-rtp.html). If you want to use speech recognition on the data you'll probably need something higher quality and closer to the raw data, and it might be worth looking at the [Java Speech API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/index.jsp).